# Correctness of “je ne connais (pas) personne”

Tags: grammaire, négation, double-négation

Is this negative sentence correct?

> Je ne connais personne qui sache lire le latin.

Should I add "pas" after "connais"?

Answer (score 3):

*Pas personne* is not grammatical.

Should you want to add *pas* after *connais*, you would need to add *de* or *une* too:

> Je ne connais **pas de** personne qui sache lire le latin.
>
> Je ne connais **pas une** personne qui sache lire le latin.

This form works too:

> Je ne connais **aucune** personne qui sache lire le latin.

In these three sentences, *personne* is no more a pronoun but a substantive, so they are not cases of double negation.

Answer (score 1):

Surtout pas! il y aurait une double négation avec "personne".

Answer (score 1):

You can however say:

> Je ne connais pas quelqu'un qui sache lire le latin.

Comment: This is not idiomatic at all. It sounds like you're saying you don't know someone if they read Latin.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm saying and I wrote "I don't know someone who knows how to read latin". It might not be idiomatic but it is as correct as "Je ne connais pas de mathématicien qui sache diviser par zéro."

Comment: I do not think it is correct. There is a crucial difference between your answer and "Je ne connais pas de mathématicien qui sache diviser par zéro.": the preposition **de**. And since you can't say "de quelqu'un", you have to write "de personne", as in "je ne connais pas de personne [...]". And then you get back to jilliagre's answer.